# WordPress get_posts does not work with a large number of posts

Tags: wordpress

I need to query all WordPress posts and create an array that contains all the value of a custom field for all posts.

This is what I previously used that worked for a small number of posts.

```
//Get all the posts
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit'),
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

//Get all the values and put them in an array
$custom_field_array = array();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $custom_field_array[] = (int)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true );
}
```

That worked fine when the number of posts was not very large, but I now need to get the `my_custom_field` value for over 5,000 posts (and growing).

Once the number of posts gets too large `get_posts` doesn't return anything. Maybe the memory required is too large, I'm not sure, but now I now need to get the `my_custom_field` value for over 5,000 posts and it doesn't work for that many posts.

How else can I get these values?

Or is there something else I can do to keep `get_posts` working with a large number of posts?

Comment: you need wordpress standard query using `WP_Query` and also limit query with fields args too

Answer (score 0):

You can also get all the post by MYSQL Select query.

```
 global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'my_custom_field' 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'my_custom_post_type'
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
     ";

     $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

     print_r($pageposts);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to wrap it in a function and pass the my_custom_post_type in with a function parameter, but it's not working: https://pastebin.com/dZ0n6bUw Any tips?

Comment: please con-cat the post type correctly like AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = "' . $post_type . '" or you can also try by echo $querystr;die; and run the die query directly in mysql from phpmyadmin.